# How to create docker image from existing AMI

Tags: docker, jenkins

I have an existing jenkins server with few pipelines running on EC2 and I have to create a docker image from this instance and have to run this created jenkins image. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Note: I have tried creating docker image from the existing jenkins and ran it and im able to run with bin/bash but unable to start jenkins or do port publish

Comment: How did you created docker image from that existing jenkins ? `Dockerfile` or `docker commit` ? Please provide more information and error messages.

Comment: I have mounted (in  /mnt) the jenkins server instance volume to another server which has docker configured and used below command to create docker image 
tar -c -C /mnt . |docker import - <myimagename>....now when i run docker images Im able to see the created image and can able to run with tty but unable to publish container port (on which jenkins is running) to the host

Comment: Working with tty
root@ip-172-31-12-161:~# docker run -ti myjenkins /bin/bash
[root@21978740a1e6 /]#
Not working when i use below port publishing method
root@ip-172-31-12-161:~# docker run -d -p 8080:8080 myjenkins
docker: Error response from daemon: No command specified.
See 'docker run --help'

Comment: Looks like you lost default command at this line `docker run -d -p 8080:8080 myjenkins [yourcommand]`